# Xcode: malloc size doesn't seem to matter

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, xcode, malloc

In the codes below, I can change the parameter of malloc to whatever values (at least the ones I have tried), and everything looks okay.

For example, I can change "3 * sizeof(float)" to "3 * sizeof(char)", or even zero. And I can still get the "correct" results. The heap size doesn't seem to matter at all.

This really confuses me. How can this happen?

The codes are written and run in Xcode 5.

```
float *favorites = malloc(3 * sizeof(float));

favorites[0] = 3.14158;
favorites[1] = 2.71828;
favorites[2] = 1.41421;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("%.4f is favorite %d\n", favorites[i], i);
}

free(favorites);
favorites = NULL;
```

Comment: Memory is commonly allocated in chunks that are multiples of 16 bytes.  Since your array only occupies 12 bytes, the amount of memory you request doesn't matter much. Try filling your array with a much larger number of entries if you want the program to crash.

Comment: Thank you @JensGustedt, I did try to search for similar questions first but didn't find the one in your comment.

Comment: For me the reference to that question is given in the right column of your question. This is a strong indication that it should have been suggested by the site when entering your question text.

Comment: Thanks @JensGustedt, you are right. I will pay more attention to that section in future. I don't want to delete my question though, so I've flagged it as a duplicate.

Comment: You can also write: `favorites[3]=3.333;favorites[4]=4.4444;favorites[5]=5.65555;...` and so on and so on. Who cares if app accidently crush.

Comment: One of the fundamental principles in C programming (or programming in general) is that you won't necessarily get punished for mistakes instantly. You sometimes _seem to get away_ with undefined behaviour. This is, however, no reason to get sloppy - for any nontrivial program, such mistakes will bite you sooner or later and produce hard to find crashes.
So it's in your own interest to avoid UB!

Comment: Many thanks @mfro, actually I didn't know there is such a thing called "undefined behaviour" before I posted this questions. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because by doing so your program invokes [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Once UB invoked, all bets are off. You may get either expected or unexpected result.

Now try to do it without allocating memory to `favoritee`

```
float *favorites ;
...
```

and see what happen?

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Actually I have not heard of undefined behavior before. Thanks for helping me learn something new here.

Answer (score 1):

Your program only looks like it works. In fact malloc internally allocates a big chunk of memory (at least one memory page) and returns pointer inside this memory area.

So, your pointer points somewhere to the beginning of memory page and nothing happens if you cross the border a little bit. If you pass the border too much (more than 4KB or 4MB) you will get an error.

Also if you call two mallocs and then pass over the range of the first allocated space, you will have problems, because malloc stores some of its internal data before returned pointer.

Anyway, from the language point of view, you have invoked an "undefined behaviour" which means nobody cares what happens if you do this. The behaviour of your program may change from one compiler version to another, from one system to another ...